# Object leaves a trail on alpha background

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, shader, fbo

What is a standard reason for this behavior? I have 2 the same buffers with 2 textures of mesh with premultiplied alpha and alpha background: in the first I have object on background, but the second leaves object trail behind itself when I move it on this alpha background. I can't realise why! FBO's are similar.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Not clearing the buffer

Comment: Exactly, you are right! My mistake was clearing before when my second FBO was binded.

Comment: This is actually a nice effect.

Comment: Yeah! I'll keep it on mind when I will be making my Photoshop )))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake was I forgot to bind FBO before clearing:

```
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); // WRONG!

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); // RIGHT!
```